# Did Am Israel pray for the mann to fall in the desert?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, mon-manna, exodus

The people of Israel in the desert: should pray for the mann to fall the next day? Because it was sure that the mann will fall the next morning. If yes: does anyone know what prayer they should say?

Answer (score 3):

[Yoma 76a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.76a.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Why didn’t the mann fall for Israel in larger amounts - maybe enough
> for a year? A mashal: A king had a son; he gave his son parnassah for
> a year, and his son came to see him once a year. So he got up and made
> it a daily portion - and his son came to see him every day. So in the
> desert, every day every Jew with a few kids would be a little nervous:
> my family is starving. All of them would turn to G-d and pray properly
> to their father in heaven.